# is there a value member property in an Android list adapter?

Tags: android, android-listview, adapter

Is it possible in adapter in android to a display member and a value member?meaning that the value member of a listView would be hidden

Comment: Can you explain what you want?

Comment: Ok maybe i need to elaborate a little more.Sorry if i've been to vague.I have a list of objects,which have a name and an id.So when i try to load them into the adapter i run the list and get the names.But when i try to retrieve the code i have to match the selected string with the list of objects,the problem appears when two objects have the same name as always the first's code would be retrieved.In C# when using a list you can choose a display member (like thename) and a valumember(like the id).So that's what my question is about.Hope i more clear now thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is build a custom `Adapter` that holds a list of objects.

Object

```
public class MyObject {
    private int id;
    private String name;
}
```

Adapter

```
public class MyObjectListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyObject> {
    private final Context  context;

    public MyObjectListAdapter(Context context, List<MyObject> objects) {
        super(context, R.layout.listview_myobjects, objects);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_myobject_item, parent, false);

        TextView textViewName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textViewObjectName);

        MyObject current = getItem(position);
        textViewName.setText(current.getName());
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Lars Vogel goes in to details about `ListView`, so for more information, look here:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html